# The default text color for all UILabels

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

I want to set the default text color for all UILabels in my app. I found this:

```
UILabel.appearance().textColor = UIColor.red
```

This works, but when I want to set some other color for a particular label in its storyboard, it cannot be done - all labels are still red.

Is it possible to define a default text color for all UILabels by setting it in storyboards and then change it for some UILabels ALSO in storyboards (not in code)? Or set the default color in code using the Appearance API and change it for some labels in storyboard?

Comment: Don't know if it's possible, but have you tried by defining the runtime attribute (`textColor`) in the storyboard? It might be applied after the appearance

Comment: I created extension for UILabel with @IBInspectable property `color`. I use it in InterfaceBuilder and set color to green, but when i run code then my label is still red

Comment: @AdrianBobwski,SubcLass Label because using extension you have to cal the extension methods yourself. Subclassing as given in below answer will automate the changes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

SubClass you labels with CustomLabel.swift. You can set text color using `IBDesignable` property named as `txtColor`

Below is the code working example

```
import UIKit

    @IBDesignable  class CustomLabel: UILabel {

        @IBInspectable var txtColor: UIColor = UIColor.grayColor() {
            didSet {
                self.textColor = txtColor
            }
        }

        func setup() {
           self.textColor = txtColor
        }

        override func awakeFromNib() {
            setup()
        }

        override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
            setup()
        }

    }
```

Comment: I created extension for UILabel with @IBInspectable property `color`. I use it in InterfaceBuilder and set color to green, but when i run code then my label is still red

Comment: Ok now it works, however. Is there no way to do this without creating a subclass?

Comment: No there is no other way

Comment: @IBDesignable does not work for class extensions. You can add the tag, but it has no effect.

Comment: If i remove default appearance for UILabel then my tag work

Comment: you can post your approach as an answer and accept your own answer. It will help others in future.

Comment: Your solution is not ideal, but it is much better than mine. And your solution works with the default color

Answer (score 9):

There is also an alternative to what Muhammad suggested.
The alternative is to use the UIAppearance proxy, but specify the classes where it would be applied to.

In that case, you would use it like this:

```
UILabel.appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses([MyViewController.self, MyotherViewController.self]).textColor = UIColor.red
```

The above though, would only allow you to set the textColor your self in some classes. in  those where the proxy is set to be enabled, you won't be able to set the text color.

It's up to you to choose which approach is better for your case

Comment: In my application I have a lot of ViewControllers, so I have to set a single global color, and only in some places I have set another

Comment: Like I said, it depends on your needs. In your case obviously this is not an ideal solution, so Muhammad's solution will suite you better